# Python double integral taking too long to compute

Tags: python, integral

I am trying to compute the `fresnel integral` over a grid of coordinates using `dblquad`. But its taking very long and finally it's not giving any result.

Below is my code. In this code I integrated only over a 10 x 10 grid but I need to integrate at least over a 500 x 500 grid.

```
import time
st = time.time()
import pylab
import scipy.integrate as inte
import numpy as np
print 'imhere 0'
def sinIntegrand(y,x, X , Y):
    a = 0.0001
    R = 2e-3
    z = 10e-3
    Lambda = 0.5e-6
    alpha = 0.01
    k  = np.pi * 2 / Lambda
    return  np.cos(k * (((x-R)**2)*a + (R-(x**2 + y**2)) * np.tan(np.radians(alpha)) + ((x - X)**2 + (y - Y)**2) / (2 * z)))
print 'im here 1'
def cosIntegrand(y,x,X,Y):
    a = 0.0001
    R = 2e-3
    z = 10e-3
    Lambda = 0.5e-6
    alpha = 0.01
    k  = np.pi * 2 / Lambda
    return  np.sin(k * (((x-R)**2)*a + (R-(x**2 + y**2)) * np.tan(np.radians(alpha)) + ((x - X)**2 + (y - Y)**2) / (2 * z)))
def y1(x,R = 2e-3):
    return (R**2 - x**2)**0.5
def y2(x, R = 2e-3):
   return -1*(R**2 - x**2)**0.5
points = np.linspace(-1e-3,1e-3,10)
points2 = np.linspace(1e-3,-1e-3,10)
yv,xv = np.meshgrid(points , points2)
#def integrate_on_grid(func, lo, hi,y1,y2):
#    """Returns a callable that can be evaluated on a grid."""
#    return np.vectorize(lambda n,m: dblquad(func, lo, hi,y1,y2,(n,m))[0])
#
#intensity = abs(integrate_on_grid(sinIntegrand,-1e-3 ,1e-3,y1, y2)(yv,xv))**2 + abs(integrate_on_grid(cosIntegrand,-1e-3 ,1e-3,y1, y2)(yv,xv))**2
Intensity = []
print 'im here2'
for i in points:
    row = []
    for j in points2:
        print 'im here'
        intensity = abs(inte.dblquad(sinIntegrand,-1e-3 ,1e-3,y1, y2,(i,j))[0])**2 + abs(inte.dblquad(cosIntegrand,-1e-3 ,1e-3,y1, y2,(i,j))[0])**2
        row.append(intensity)
    Intensity.append(row)
Intensity = np.asarray(Intensity)
pylab.imshow(Intensity,cmap = 'gray')
pylab.show()
print str(time.time() - st)
```

I would really appreciate if you could tell any better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `scipy.integrate.dblquad` to calculate every pixel of your image is going to be slow in any case.

You should try rewriting your mathematical problem  so you can use some classical function in `scipy.special` instead.  For instance, `scipy.special.fresnel` might work, although it is 1D and your problem seems to be in 2D. Otherwise,  that there is a [relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) between the Fresnel integral and the incomplete Gamma function (`scipy.special.gammainc`), if that helps.

If none of this work, as a last resort you can spend time optimizing your code and adapting it to Cython. This it will probably give a speed up of a factor of 10 to 100 (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15794220/1791279)). Though this wouldn't be sufficient to go from a grid `10x10` to a grid `500x500`.